# cant navigate the playground

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im using ros hydro, ubuntu 12.04 .. im working on Make a map and navigate with it using gazebo http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it . but i cant navigate the playground, i got this error [ERROR] [1406213257.254638543]: Map_server could not open ~/home/hattan_map5.
process[navigation_velocity_smoother-4]: started with pid [9439]
[map_server-2] process has died [pid 9329, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/map_server/map_server ~/home/hattan_map5 __name:=map_server __log:=/home/hattan/.ros/log/7297b3bc-1341-11e4-a206-74e5433742d1/map_server-2.log].
log file: /home/hattan/.ros/log/7297b3bc-1341-11e4-a206-74e5433742d1/map_server-2*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189221/cant-navigate-the-playground/) by [haider](https://answers.ros.org/users/18016/haider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believ this error is caused by the pathing described here

> ~/home/hattan_map5

Try using the absolute path to where this is located (you can find this out by typing `pwd` in the directory where the map is). Additionally, when you created a map using the map_server, it should have saved to two files: one with the extension `.pgm` and one with the extension `.yaml`. Make sure to run `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=<full path to your map file>.yaml`, and make certain that the image attribute in the`.yaml` file correctly points to the path of the `.pgm`.

To clarify, if your files are located at `/home/hattan/hattan_map5.yaml` and `/home/hattan/hattan_map5.pgm`, then inside the .yaml file should be the line `image: hattan_map5.pgm`, and you would run `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/hattan/hattan_map5.yaml`

---

Originally posted by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) with karma: 301 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haider](https://answers.ros.org/users/18016/haider/) on 2014-08-07**:
thank you very much . it works very well